# regex ^ and $ are not working

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to  write a regex that matches a number with commas for
every three digits? It must match the following:

```
'42'
'1,234'
'6,368,745'
```

but not the following:

```
'12,34,567' (which has only two digits between the commas)
'1234' (which lacks commas)
```

so I have tried the following

```
((^\d{1,3})((\,\d{3})*$)) 
^\d{1,3}(,{3})*$
^(\d{1,3}(,{3})*)$
```

but it didn't match anything.
when I tried without ^ and $ then it is not matching the exact pattern.

Comment: `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$`?

Comment: `(,{3})` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Without actually trying it, I'm guessing: `^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$`

Comment: This isn’t your specific problem, but for the sake of future Googler’s I’m going to link [this post about regex dialects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/22975). You just seem to be missing a `\d` in your second attempt, which otherwise would have worked.

Comment: If you claim that `^` or `$` doesn't work, you need to be prepared to demonstrate that some guarantee in their documentation is being broken. This does nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prithvi,

your first regex works, actually.

Try this test:

```
import re

REGEX = re.compile("((^\d{1,3})((\,\d{3})*$))")

for test in ('42', '1,234', '6,368,745', '12,34,567', '1234'):
    print(test, REGEX.match(test) != None)
```

The output is (python 3)

```
42 True
1,234 True
6,368,745 True
12,34,567 False
1234 False
```

UPDATE

prithvi asked in the comment about a regex that could be used in the `findall` method. Since the answer is a bit lengthy I put it here.

For `findall` the regex should have boundaries, that match something that is not a part of the number.

I suppose, the boundary **before** the match is either string beginning or a string that is neither digit nor comma. I encode such boundary as `(?:^|(?<=[^0-9,]))`

Same with the boundary **after** - it is either end of string or something that is neither digit nor comma: `(?:(?=[^0-9,])|$)`

How those regex are built.

- `?:` designates a group that is not included in the group list. I use for cleaner math result
- `?<=[^0-9,]` is a a positive lookbehind assertion. It means, that the following regex matches if and only if it is preceded by something that matches `[^0-9,]` (that is neither a digit nor a comma)
- `?=[^0-9,]` is a lookbehind assertion. It means, that the preceding part of regex matches if and only if it is followed by something that matches `[^0-9,]` (that is neither a digit nor a comma)

Here is an example:

```
REGEX = re.compile("(?:^|(?<=[^0-9,]))(\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*)(?:(?=[^0-9,])|$)")
long_str = '42 1,234 6,368,745 12,34,567 1234'
print(REGEX.findall(long_str))
```

The result is `['1,234', '42', '6,368,745']`

Comment: thanks, but in above code you have used it as a pattern match,  is there any way to filter the all the matches from a string by using findall function?

Comment: @prithvi, please have a look at the update of the response.

Comment: @Hi Pak Uula, that works perfectly, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/3Mkuu6/2)

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$
```

Assuming you don't want to allow `0,123` you can use `^[1-9]{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$` instead.

---

### Results

#### Input

```
42
1,234
1,234

12,34,567
1234
```

#### Output

Below are matches only.

```
42
1,234
1,234
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `\d{1,3}` Match any digit between 1 and 3 times
- `(?:,\d{3})*` Match any number of a comma `,` followed by exactly 3 digits
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: This is Python, not PCRE. That doesn’t make a difference in this case, but it would be better to link to https://regex101.com/r/3Mkuu6/2.

Comment: @DanielH thanks. I updated. I know it doesn't matter for this case, so I didn't pay much attention to it, but I suppose I should have.